# error: deleteItem function is not defined in my script

Tags: javascript

I wrote a to do list in javascript but this code dose not work and show a deleteItem() is not defined error. I test it in codepen and it works correctly.

```
window.onload = function () {
let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourform");
let ourField = document.getElementById("todo");
let ourList = document.getElementById("list");

ourForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createItem(ourField.value);
});

function createItem(x) {
    let ourHtml = `<li>${x}<button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
    ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ourHtml);
    ourField.value = "";
    ourField.focus();
}

function deleteItem(elementToDelete) {
    elementToDelete.parentElement.remove();
}
```

}

```
<h1>NEED-TO-DO APP</h1>
<form id="ourform">
    <input id="todo" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <button>Create Item</button>
</form>
<h3>Need To Do</h3>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

whats wrong with my script ..

Comment: Try to keep these createItem and deleteItem function out of window onload

Answer (score 2):

Try copying the `deleteItem` function outside `window.onload` function as the scope is not accessible right now.

```
  window.onload = function () {
    let ourForm = document.getElementById("ourform");
    let ourField = document.getElementById("todo");
    let ourList = document.getElementById("list");

    ourForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      createItem(ourField.value);
    });

    function createItem(x) {
      let ourHtml = `<li>${x}<button onclick="deleteItem(this)">Delete</button></li>`;
      ourList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ourHtml);
      ourField.value = "";
      ourField.focus();
    }

  }
  function deleteItem(elementToDelete) {
    elementToDelete.parentElement.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct
you can delete this line given under below

```
window.onload = function () {
```

then you code will work perfect
thank you